# Is there a command to view Primary Volume Descriptor in iso images?

Tags: terminal, software-recommendation, command-line

I use `isoinfo` to do it on Linux. Is there an `isoinfo` like command on macOS?

[ISO 9660 - 3.3 The Primary Volume Descriptor](http://wiki.osdev.org/ISO_9660#The_Primary_Volume_Descriptor)

An example of `isoinfo`'s output:

```
$ isoinfo -debug -d -i Win10_1607_Japanese_x64.iso 
CD-ROM is in ISO 9660 format
System id: 
Volume id: CCSA_X64FRE_JA-JP_DV5
Volume set id: CCSA_X64FRE_JA-JP_DV5
Publisher id: MICROSOFT CORPORATION
Data preparer id: MICROSOFT CORPORATION, ONE MICROSOFT WAY, REDMOND WA 98052, (425) 882-8080
Application id: CDIMAGE 2.56 (01/01/2005 TM)
Copyright File id: 
Abstract File id: 
Bibliographic File id: 
Volume set size is: 1
Volume set sequence number is: 1
Logical block size is: 2048
Volume size is: 2122293
Root directory extent:  26 size: 112
Path table size is:     10
L Path table start:     23
L Path opt table start: 0
M Path table start:     24
M Path opt table start: 0
Creation Date:     2016 07 16 15:46:30.00
Modification Date: 0000 00 00 00:00:00.00
Expiration Date:   0000 00 00 00:00:00.00
Effective Date:    0000 00 00 00:00:00.00
File structure version: 1
El Torito VD version 1 found, boot catalog is in sector 22
NO Joliet present
NO Rock Ridge present
Eltorito validation header:
    Hid 1
    Arch 0 (x86)
    ID 'Microsoft Corporation'
    Key 55 AA
    Eltorito defaultboot header:
        Bootid 88 (bootable)
        Boot media 0 (No Emulation Boot)
        Load segment 0
        Sys type 0
        Nsect 8
        Bootoff 21B 539
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `drutil` command is the OS X utility that's similar to isoinfo. The `dumpiso` verb inspects and interprets ISO-9660 and Joliet structures. The format of the command is:

```
drutil dumpiso <device> <block> [format]
```

where the arguments are (see `man drutil` for details):

```
device   Disk node, e.g. /dev/disk1.

block    Block number to dump.

format   If format is not specified dumpiso will attempt to guess. 
         If present, this argument should be one of the following:
         None, Boot, BootCat, PVD, SVD, VPD, VDST, MPath, LPath,
         Dir, or HFSPlusVH.
```

The `drutil` command allows a shortcut that avoids the need to attach, mount or detach an ISO image file. The command is:

```
drutil dumpiso <image> <block>
```

where `<image>` is the name of an ISO image file. For example, `drutil dumpiso image.iso 16` displays block 16 from an image file named `image.iso` and guesses the block's format.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I could not find a way to use drutil to make an output like isoinfo's.

Comment: `drutil` and `isoinfo` are *similar* in that they both display ISO-9660 structures, but they are not *identical* so one can't expect the output to be the same.

Comment: The command should be something like this:  


    $ DEVICE=`hdiutil attach Win10_1607_Japanese_x64.iso -nomount` && drutil dumpiso $DEVICE 16 && hdiutil detach $DEVICE

Comment: I noticed that I can assign an iso file as device directly.  
e,g,  
    $ drutil dumps Win10_1607_Japanese_x64.iso 16

Comment: @user218669 Yes, I left out how to attach or mount an ISO image file. Your shortcut in the form: `drutil dumpiso <image> <block>` avoids the need to attach the image file to a device.